# Job parameters are getting cached

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

> Blockquote

I am facing a problem with jobParameters in spring batch.I have a jobParameter which is optional.For the first time when i am passing job parameter through commandLineJobRunner it is working.For the second time i am not passing any jobParameter but still it is taking the previous jobParameter.When i clear my Meta-Data then jobParameter is coming as null i am not passing.How can i fix this without clearing the Meta-Data.Is this happens normally in spring batch

edited code

I am using MapJobRegistry and next is used while launching the job.When i debugged i have observed that to  increment the run.id it is loading all the previous parameters

```
public JobParameters More ...getNext(JobParameters parameters) {
        if (parameters == null) {
            parameters = new JobParameters();
        }
        long id = parameters.getLong(key, 0L) + 1;
        return new JobParametersBuilder(parameters).addLong(key, id).toJobParameters();
    }
```

Comment: Are you using SpringBoot and is your job executed through 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner'?

Comment: No i am launching my job through commandLineJobRunner.I am not using spring boot @HansjoergWingeier

Comment: Are you using a JdbcJobRegistery or a MapJobRegistery? Do use a "next" or a "restart" option, when launching? I think the best thing for you to do is to make a breakpoint inside CommandLineJobRunner.start and check when and why your JobParameters change.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to mention is that you should not use all the Map... classes. They are not intendend for production and, therefore, you better of using the different Jdbc implementations. If you don't wanna use a real DB, you can use always an inmemory DB.

But about your initial question:
You are using the CommandLineJobRunner togehter with the option "next".
Having a look at method CommandLineJobRunner.start() you find the following lines:

```
if (opts.contains("-next")) {
    JobParameters nextParameters = getNextJobParameters(job);
    Map<String, JobParameter> map = new HashMap<String, JobParameter>(nextParameters.getParameters());
    map.putAll(jobParameters.getParameters());
    jobParameters = new JobParameters(map);
}
```

You can see that getNextJobParameters is called. Inside this method you can see that the data of the previous run is loaded 'jobExplorer.getJobInstances(jobIdentifier, 0, 1);' (if there was a previous run). If there is a previous run, then the job-parameters of this old run are returned after applying the incrementer.next method -> hence, this is the reason you get your old parameters.

Now, this is the technical explanation but the question that follows is how you should use the "next" and "restart" option in order to get what you want.

using of next:
- next works only as expected if you launch a job with the same name and the same jobparameters. Otherwise the results can be confusing. Actually, I use next only inside units and integration tests

using of restart:
- you can use "restart" if the previous jobexecution with the same jobname failed. Also here, the jobparameters will be taken from your previous launch.

For a normal start of a job, you shouldn't be using next nor restart. A normal start of a job should always have a unique jobparameter. For instance, a "runid" whose value is changed with every start of the job. (otherwise, you would get JobInstanceAlready... Exception).

In case of unit tests, I use a unique "runId" for every testcase. And here, I'm using the "next" option.

Comment: is there any JDBC impl availaable for JobRegistry.If i dnt use next for launching my job for the first time it is working as expected.but for second time the job is not starting

Comment: JDBC vs. Map Registry: google or look here http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-batch-jobrepository-example/

Comment: Why did the second launch of the job not work? did you get an exception? did you use a parameter with a new unique value?

Comment: I started my first job without next it was running fine but Meta tables are not populated with the job details.When i run for the second time with different parameter job is not started.No exception was coming.